# C++ Assignment With Nested loops And 2-d Arrays

Tags: c++

Need Help with a little class assignment, I've been working on this one for a few days and i just cant get it to run properly.
Here's the assignment requirements:

Write a program using nested loops that asks the user to enter a value for the number of rows to display. It should then display that many rows of asterisks, with one asterisk in the first row, two in the second row, and so on. For each row, the asterisks are preceded by the number of periods needed to make all the rows display a total number of characters equal to the number of rows. A sample run would look like this: 
Enter number of rows: 5 
….*

…**

..***

.****

*****

This is the best i could do:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int n;
    int col;
    int row;
    cout << "Please enter a number to determine how big the 2-d array will be.\n"; 
    cin >> n;
    char asterisks[n][n];
    for ( row = 0; row < n; row++) 
    { 
        for (col = 0; col < n; ++col) 
        asterisks[row][col] = '.';
    }
    for (col = n; col < 0; col--
    {
        for (row = n; row < 0; --row)
        asterisks[row][col] = '*';
        cout << asterisks[row][col];
        cout << endl;
    }
system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

The output is:

Please enter a number to determine how big the 2-d array will be.
5
Press any key to continue

Comment: This is not valid C++: `    cin >> n;
    char asterisks[n][n];`.

Comment: There's also a `)` missing at `for (col = n; col < 0; col--`.

Comment: `char asterisks[n][n];` -- Another new coder has fallen into the VLA trap.  This code is not valid.

Comment: no this code wont produce any output. Please read about [mcve] and make sure that the code you show matches the behaviour you describe

Comment: You don't need a 2D array tio do this task. Just print out the asterisks and dots. Why confuse things by putting then in an array first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, no 2d arrays used.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Please enter a number to determine how big the 2-d array will be.\n"; 
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int row = 0; row < n; ++row) 
    { 
        for (int col = 0; col < n; ++col) 
        {
            if (row + col < n - 1)
                cout << '.';
            else
                cout << '*';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Think about the problem, you need to print a square of characters, that's nested for loops. And you need to decide in each place whether to print a `*` or a `.` that's what `if (row + col < n - 1)` does.

There's no need to save data in a 2D array.

Comment: Thanks for the help!